# How to overcome Duplicate class issue while using Google Places SDK

Tags: android, gradle

I am converting my android app from older version of places SDK to the newer one as the older one is being decommissioned from July 29th. I made the changes as suggested by the documentation.

While compiling , I see loads of duplicate class error messages from classes that I don't use it evidently from my own code. Though they could used in libraries.

```
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModule found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GenericTransitionOptions found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Glide found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.GlideContext found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.ListPreloader found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.ListPreloader$PreloadModelProvider found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.ListPreloader$PreloadSizeProvider found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.ListPreloader$PreloadTarget found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.ListPreloader$PreloadTargetQueue found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.MemoryCategory found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Priority found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Registry found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Registry$MissingComponentException found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoImageHeaderParserException found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoResultEncoderAvailableException found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoSourceEncoderAvailableException found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder$2 found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager found in modules classes.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
```

I came up across the repo's issues page but see no worthwhile updates

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3527

here goes my build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 28
    versionName '3.7'
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        lintOptions {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false

        }
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // picks the JavaMail license file
}
productFlavors {
}

}buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
    }
}
}

dependencies {



implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'


implementation 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.2'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'


implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'


implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.1'
implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.1.0'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'


implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.0'
implementation 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried to exclude the classes for compilation using gradle but I seem to be doing something wrong here (Quite new to Gradle though).

```
configurations {

    compile.exclude group: 'com.bumptech.glide' , module: 'glide'

}
```

Is this snippet fine to exclude those classes being compiled ? and could I just add them in app's build.gradle?

Thank you so much for your inputs. Much appreciated

Comment: Did you clean the project? If not, you can click `Build → Clean` at Android Studio or run `gradlew clean` command.

Comment: Yup did that already. Didn't help either.

Comment: Did you get any solutions for this.... I am facing same issue.

Comment: Hi @URAndroid , If I remember right I had to change all the android.* based implementations to androidx.* in the gradle file and do the painstaking work of changing the xml file headers accordingly. Do give it a try.

Let me know if that works , or else I could recheck my code as what I did to resolve it. But yes I managed to get my code working. So a solution does exist.